# Unable to parse back SQL expression string generated by spark itself

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running into a scenario where I need to convert spark expression to sql expression, and later need to parse sql expression back to spark expression. In most of the cases it work fine, but in some cases it throws error.

For example following works fine in spark

```
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = Seq("Britain", "Germany", "USA", "Russia", "Japan").toDF("Country")

val japan = 'Country === "Japan"
df.filter(japan).show 
val sqlExp = japan.expr.sql
println(sqlExp) // output: (`Country` = 'Japan')
df.filter(expr(sqlExp)).show
```

But when I try same with following expression it fails:

```
val expression = 'Country.contains("S")
println(expression.expr.sql)
df.filter(expression).show
val parsedExpression = expr(expression.expr.sql) //output: contains(`Country`, 'S')
df.filter(parsedExpression).show
```

It seems like it works with only standard sql syntax. When I use `expr("country LIKE '%S%'")` it is able to parse.

> Is there a way to parse back such an sql expression (that is generated by spark) to spark expression?

Comment: what is the error message you get? also, i see no such function `contains` in [Spark-SQL documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Expression.sql`  method:

- Is not a part of officially public API (as stated many times by the developers code in `o.a.s.sql.catalyst` should be considered "weakly" private).
- Is not explictly intended to generate valid SQL string and  can be even an arbitrary string./

  In fact `contains(`Country`, 'S')` is valid in neither `sql` (or `spark-sql`) nor `expr`.